# What's wrong my code to create a GL texture from an SDL_Surface?

Tags: opengl, textures, sdl

I have an issue here with converting an existing SDL_Surface into an OpenGL texture. 
The texture gets created, but it's a plain white texture, below is a screenshot of the result:
[image: Screenshot of Result]

It seems to me that the SDL_Surface image data is not being properly cast onto the OpenGL texture. But I'm unsure why. Below is another screenshot, showing the image data of the "Loaded_Image", which is the existing SDL_Surface. 
[image: Screenshot of Existing Image Data]

I'm just a bit unsure where I'm going wrong. The code seems alright to me:

```
SDLib::Image SDLib::ConvertImage(SDL_Surface* surface)
{
    SDL_Surface *LoadedImage = NULL;
    GLuint tempTexture;
    Image tempImage;
    LoadedImage = surface;

    //Set Width/Height Of Image
    tempImage.width = LoadedImage->w;
    tempImage.height = LoadedImage->h;

    SDL_Surface *image = SDL_CreateRGBSurface(0, LoadedImage->w, LoadedImage->h, 16, 0xff000000, 0x00ff0000, 0x0000ff00, 0x000000ff);
    SDL_BlitSurface(LoadedImage, NULL, image, NULL);

    glGenTextures(1, &tempTexture);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tempTexture);

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_BGRA, image->w, image->h, 0, GL_BGRA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image->pixels);

    //Finally Set The TempTexture data for our OpenGl Texture to the Temporary Image Struct
    tempImage.texData = tempTexture;

    return tempImage;
}
```

The image itself it supposed to rendering out like this for reference:

[image: Expected Output]

Comment: Check the return value of SDL_BlitSurface, [here](http://www.libsdl.org/docs/html/sdlblitsurface.html) is its Doc

Comment: It returns -1 :/, so an error somewhere is occurring.

Comment: If you found the problem, you should answer your own question and mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are using wrong color masks when you create your `image` surface. Try this for a GL_BGRA texture:

```
SDL_Surface *image = SDL_CreateRGBSurface(0, LoadedImage->w, LoadedImage->h, 16, 0x00ff0000, 0x0000ff00, 0x000000ff, 0xff000000);
```

Though, a better solution for loading images would be to use something like this (from [gpwiki](https://web.archive.org/web/20160321223122/http://content.gpwiki.org:80/index.php/SDL:Tutorials:Using_SDL_with_OpenGL)):

```
// get the number of channels in the SDL surface
nOfColors = surface->format->BytesPerPixel;
if (nOfColors == 4)     // contains an alpha channel
{
    if (surface->format->Rmask == 0x000000ff)
        texture_format = GL_RGBA;
    else
                texture_format = GL_BGRA;
} else if (nOfColors == 3)     // no alpha channel
{
    if (surface->format->Rmask == 0x000000ff)
        texture_format = GL_RGB;
    else
        texture_format = GL_BGR;
} else {
    printf("warning: the image is not truecolor..  this will probably break\n");
    // this error should not go unhandled
}

// Have OpenGL generate a texture object handle for us
glGenTextures( 1, &texture );

// Bind the texture object
glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture );

// Set the texture's stretching properties
    glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR );
    glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR );

// Edit the texture object's image data using the information SDL_Surface gives us
glTexImage2D( GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, nOfColors, surface->w, surface->h, 0,
                  texture_format, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, surface->pixels );
```

That way you can even skip blitting your image to a surface and make a texture right away.

Comment: Make certain that you watch your pixel store alignments if uploading 3-component textures (http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Common_Mistakes#Texture_upload_and_pixel_reads) and also note that use of 1, 2, 3 or 4 for the internalFormat param of glTexImage2D is deprecated in modern core contexts.